# Stop PyCharm from going into pydev files on exceptions

Tags: pycharm

Is there a way to stop PyCharm from opening pydev files on syntax errors all the time?

If you write a simple one liner with a syntax error like below:

```
a = [ 1, 2,
```

where there closing bracket is missing, PyCharm will open the `_pydev_execfile.py` file to break on exec line. Any way to stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open *Breakpoints* window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> (or click on an icon with two small red dots in debugger window) and uncheck **Suspend** under **Python Exception Breakpoint > Any exception**.

[image: Breakpoints window]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.